# How to identify emails where sender is also a recipient?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to export sender email address and recipient email addresses (to and cc) to Excel. I adapted code I found online. It does most of what I need but there are two problems:

- It only works with a single recipient. If there are two or more recipients, it provides names (e.g. Jo Bloggs) instead of email addresses.
- It only includes people in the 'To' field, not those in the 'CC' field.

I think the bit that needs fixing is:

```vb
'trying to get recipient email address
 Dim olEU2 As Outlook.ExchangeUser
 Dim oEDL2 As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
 Dim recip2 As Outlook.Recipient
 Set recip2 = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(strColE)

     Select Case recip2.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
         Set olEU2 = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
         If Not (olEU2 Is Nothing) Then
             strColE = olEU2.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry
         Set olEU2 = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
         If Not (olEU2 Is Nothing) Then
            strColE = olEU2.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
         Set oEDL2 = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
         If Not (oEDL2 Is Nothing) Then
            strColE = olEU2.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
     End Select
```

Full code:

```vb
Option Explicit
 Sub CopyToExcel()
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath As String

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim obj As Object
 Dim olItem 'As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim strColA, strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE, strColF As String
               
' Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
strPath = enviro & "\Documents\Book1.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next
  ' Open the workbook to input the data
  ' Create workbook if doesn't exist
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
If Err <> 0 Then
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
      xlWB.SaveAs FileName:=strPath
End If
   On Error GoTo 0
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
On Error Resume Next
' add the headers if not present
If xlSheet.Range("A1") = "" Then
  xlSheet.Range("A1") = "Sender Name"
  xlSheet.Range("B1") = "Sender Email"
  xlSheet.Range("C1") = "Subject"
  xlSheet.Range("D1") = "Body"
  xlSheet.Range("E1") = "Sent To"
  xlSheet.Range("F1") = "Date"
End If

'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
'needed for Exchange 2016. Remove if causing blank lines.
rCount = rCount + 1

' get the values from outlook
Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Set objFolder = objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set objItems = objFolder.Items
  For Each obj In objItems

    Set olItem = obj
    
 'collect the fields
 
    strColA = olItem.SenderName
    strColB = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
    strColC = olItem.Subject
    strColD = olItem.Body
    strColE = olItem.To
    strColF = olItem.ReceivedTime
    
    
' Get the Exchange address
' if not using Exchange, this block can be removed
 Dim olEU As Outlook.ExchangeUser
 Dim oEDL As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
 Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
 Set recip = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(strColB)

 If InStr(1, strColB, "/") > 0 Then
' if exchange, get smtp address
     Select Case recip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
         Set olEU = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
         If Not (olEU Is Nothing) Then
             strColB = olEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry
         Set olEU = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
         If Not (olEU Is Nothing) Then
            strColB = olEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
         Set oEDL = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
         If Not (oEDL Is Nothing) Then
            strColB = olEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
     End Select
End If
' End Exchange section


'trying to get recipient email address
 Dim olEU2 As Outlook.ExchangeUser
 Dim oEDL2 As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
 Dim recip2 As Outlook.Recipient
 Set recip2 = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(strColE)

     Select Case recip2.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
         Set olEU2 = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
         If Not (olEU2 Is Nothing) Then
             strColE = olEU2.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry
         Set olEU2 = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
         If Not (olEU2 Is Nothing) Then
            strColE = olEU2.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
       Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
         Set oEDL2 = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
         If Not (oEDL2 Is Nothing) Then
            strColE = olEU2.PrimarySmtpAddress
         End If
     End Select



'write them in the excel sheet
  xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = strColA
  xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = strColB
  xlSheet.Range("c" & rCount) = strColC
  xlSheet.Range("d" & rCount) = strColD
  xlSheet.Range("e" & rCount) = strColE
  xlSheet.Range("f" & rCount) = strColF
 
'Next row
  rCount = rCount + 1
xlWB.Save

 Next
 
' don't wrap lines
xlSheet.Rows.WrapText = False

xlWB.Save
     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
    
     Set olItem = Nothing
     Set obj = Nothing
     Set xlApp = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying to adapt code I found online but didn't have much luck. I'm trying a different, hopefully simpler approach now - export all the information to excel (which I am much more comfortable using) so I can identify the items where senderemailaddress is included in recipients. I've managed to adapt a code which does this but it only works with a single recipient. If there are 2 or more recipients, it just provides their name (e.g. Jo Bloggs) instead of their email address. I've copied the code into my original question - would be very grateful if someone could advise on how to adapt this.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through all items in the folder is not really a good idea. I'd recommend starting from the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods instead. Please note that there are some item properties that you can’t use for the filter. You can read more about the properties not allowed in the filter string and string formats used for the search criterion on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx).

The following example uses the `Restrict` method to get all Inbox items of Business category and moves them to the `Business` folder. To run this example, create or make sure a subfolder called 'Business' exists under `Inbox`:

```
Sub MoveItems()  
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder  
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set myFolder = _  
        myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
    Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict("[Categories] = 'Business'")  
    For i =  myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1  
        myRestrictItems(i).Move myFolder.Folders("Business")  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.

Please remember that you can set a suitable filter (View | View Settings |filter) on a folder and study the filter string on the SQL tab of the `Filter` dialog. Then you can construct any required filter string in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think my original request was a bit ambitious so I'm trying a simpler approach now (see edit to my question)

Answer (score 0):

If woudl be nice to use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`, but I cannot think of a query that would let you do what you want. If it is a one time thing, you have no choice but to loop through all items in a folder and for each item loop through all recipients and compare each recipient's entry id (`Recipient.EntryID`) with the  sender entry id (`MailItem.Sender.EntryId`).